# How to find the volume of the shape formed by function given below?

Tags: calculus

$b^2\cdot x^2+a^2\cdot y^2\:=\:a^2\cdot b^2$

a) When we rotate the given function around Ox axis.

b) When we rotate the given function around Oy axis.

Comment: As a first step: do you know what this implicit function represents?

Answer (score 0):

This is the ellipse $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1$. What is the range of $x$ and $y$ for the proposed rotations? If you're producing a full ellipsoid, then $V=4\pi ab^2/3$ for rotation about the $x$-axis and $V=4\pi a^2b/3$ for rotation about the $y$-axis.